# Is there a shortcut to find the sum in a Harmonic series with boundaries?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I'm aware that the harmonic series diverges so I won't look into that, however I haven't found any explanation of the following problem:

Is it possible to find the sum between an interval of the Harmonic sequence. Let's say, if i want to sum between the first term and the sixth like

$S_{6}= 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}$

or the sum between the fourth term and the eight like

$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}$

In these situations, does there exist a shortcut?. Or is it necessary to do it individually like any sum? (which can be very time consuming and prone to errors depending of the circumstances).

Edit:

Is there a way to calculating those values without requiring the assistance of a calculator or software? (and i'm not referring an abacus or a slide rule or any other device either electronic or mechanical).

Comment: [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) discusses them more.  I'm unaware of any speedups for computing these sums --- if you're worried about being time consuming/prone to errors, I'd suggest a computer program to do the work for you.

Comment: If it was $\sum_{i=m}^n \frac 1i$ with large values of $m,n$, the asymptotics would work quite fine.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2Fn+from+n%3D4+to+8&wal=header

Comment: [Here's](https://repl.it/MHyj/0) some Python code that computes it in "the obvious way".

Comment: @Mark and Professor Vector, I have added that the requirement is if can be done without the assistance of 'modern technology' or 'mechanical'.

Comment: I often use $\ln \frac nm $ as a good approximation for $\frac 1m + \cdots + \frac 1n$. It seems you want an exact formula without an increasing number of summands. Why would you need that?

Comment: @user334639 How approximate is the formula you proposed to the exact answer? Is it off by much or just a little. Actually it is my personal curiosity since this topic isn't covered much on the sources I have read, precalculus books and online and yes other than a formula I was looking to know if this specific situation has been studied before (let's say during middle ages, Renaissance, the enlightenment or after the industrial revolution).

Comment: A more detailed answer has been given below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that, for large $n$,

$$S_n=1+\tfrac12+\tfrac13+\cdots+\tfrac1n\approx \log(n)+\gamma$$

and as such (for large enough $n, m$,

\begin{align}
\tfrac1m+\tfrac1{m+1}+\cdots+\tfrac1n&\approx(\log(n)+\gamma)-(\log(m-1)+\gamma)\\
&=\log(n)-\log(m-1)\\
&=\log(\tfrac n{m-1})
\end{align}

---

An exact formula to compute $S_n$ (that is, one that is marginally easier to compute than it's definition) isn't known. However, one can always get closer to the actual value by using a better approximation ($B_k$ denoting bernoulli numbers):

\begin{align}
S_n&=\log(n) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{B_{2k}}{2k}\frac{1}{n^{2k}}\\
&\approx \log(n) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n}-\sum_{k=1}^{M}\frac{B_{2k}}{2k}\frac{1}{n^{2k}}
\end{align}

we can just cut off the summation at some point $M$. The bigger $M$, the closer you get to $S_n$, and for large $n$, this approximation really gets quite close. If you need the *exact* value, you're best off just computing $1+\tfrac12+\cdots+\tfrac1n$.

Comment: So, in short the answer is no, there isn't a way, right?. however by far how off is the answer from the exact value?, i mean the one which involves the use of Bernoulli's numbers. It seems that even this approximation starts from 1 but not applicable within a boundary right?.

Comment: The answer is no if you wish to compute $S_n$ exactly. If an approximation will do, then you can use the expression with bernoulli numbers and cut it off at some point to be exact enough for whatever you need it from. The expression with bernoulli numbers will get arbitrarily close depending on how far you cut off the sum, and if you don't cut it off at all, the sum is exactly $S_n$. I'd recommend using $S_n\approx \log(n)+\gamma+\frac1{2n}$ (you can check, this isn't far off even for $S_1$).

Comment: I get the idea. However from what I understood you can only cut the summation which had begun from one and not perform the operation between an interval using Bernoulli's numbers.

Comment: Well, of course you can. If you want to compute $\frac1m+\frac1{m+1}+\cdots+\frac1n$, then you simply need to see that $$\frac1m+\frac1{m+1}+\cdots+\frac1n=S_n-S_{m-1}$$ Simply substitute your approximation for $S_n$ and $S_{m-1}$ and you're done

Comment: Thanks for that. It was not very obvious to me but it is now.